# MS SQL difference between two latest records

Tags: sql-server

Given table is :

```
create table events (
      event_type integer not null,
      value integer not null,
      time timestamp not null,
      unique(event_type, time)
  );
```

need to return difference of value for event_type between latest and second latest registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lead() window function to get next record value (order by time desc for each event). row_number()=1 will give you just the first row per event_type

```
select t1.event_type, t1.value - t1.prev_value as diff
  from (
     select t.event_type,
            t.value,
            lead(t.value) over (partition by t.event_type order by time desc) prev_value,
            row_number() over (partition by t.event_type order by time desc) rn
       from events t) as t1
where rn=1
  and prev_value is not null-- this will prevent event_types with just one row
```

Comment: Great, but how to isolate only record which recorded more than 1. This returns and that which recorded once.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to check if you have a least 2 records of the same event_type?

Comment: yes, but for example, if one event_type is entered only once it will show like NONE value

Comment: @DarkoMilic ok, I updated the query to avoid records with only one row on event_type